# Inspect message output

Tags: echo-area, message

When I save my file, I can see output of some commands in the echo area. The thing is, that it's very fast and the next message will overwrite the previous one. So I just see the message `Wrote FILE`. Is there a way, how can I look on the previous messages?

Comment: The minibuffer and the echo area are in the same location. The former is for input; the latter is for output. Messages are typically written to the echo area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`M-x view-echo-area-messages RET` or `C-h e` will open the `*Messages*` buffer.

(This buffer can even contain some stuff that's not shown in the minibuffer, see `inhibit-message`.)

Comment: `C-h e` works for me, emacs says it's an alias for `view-echo-area-messages`. `M-x messages RET` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doh, that was something from my .emacs, editing … thanks :-)

Comment: `C-x 4 b *Messages*` will also get you there (completion available).